# java: creating image of your program

Tags: java, swing, screen-capture

I am trying to create an image of one of my JPanels at a fixed resolution, or at a resolution that may be bigger than the current screen resolution. Consequently I cannot use a simple screen capture method as it causes my image resolution to be dependent on the resolution of the screen, which the user sets. Is there a way around this?

Alternatively, is there a way to do this in openGL? Create a virtual buffer, render into it, then create an image based on that virtual space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create the control, you don't need to add it to any JFrame or otherwise cause it to be displayed. You can subsequently use the `print` method on it to cause it to be rendered to a `Graphics` object. You can set the size and such as you like without having to take care of the screen boundaries (as the control is never displayed on screen).

Answer (score 2):

Look at [JxCapture](http://www.teamdev.com/jxcapture/). It's a commersial product but you can get free license if you're developing open-source (or maybe even non-commercial) project.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.